# Having an problem executing an query from my php code

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Here is the $_POST array :

```
Array
(
[car_id] => ford_ka
[marca] => Teste
[modelo] => Teste
[preco] => 123
[descricao] => otimo carro teste123
[tanque] => 123
[motor] => 320cv bom blablabla
)
```

So i pass it to variables

```
$c_id = filter_var($_POST["car_id"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
$marca = filter_var($_POST["marca"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$modelo = filter_var($_POST["modelo"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$preco = filter_var($_POST["preco"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$desc = filter_var($_POST["descricao"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$tanque = filter_var($_POST["tanque"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$motor = filter_var($_POST["motor"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

I create my connection

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password,$mysql_database);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Then i prepare the data

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO cars_data (car_id, marca, modelo, preco, descricao, tanque, motor) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Bind it to markers

```
$statement->bind_param('sssisis', $c_id, $marca, $modelo, $preco, $desc, $tanque, $motor);
```

And execute it

```
 if($statement->execute()){
    print "Your car with the id " . $c_id . "has been included";
 }else{
    print $mysqli->error; 
}
 }
```

So, what i'm not getting ?

UPDATE!!!

This is the message i got from the log:
     "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\MAMP\htdocs\process.php:43 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\process.php on line 43"

Comment: You don't actually tell us what's wrong. What happens? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? What have you done to debug this?

Comment: There are two closing curly braces, maybe you never enter the execution block as you suspect? You'll need to define the current behavior.

Comment: PD of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/845021) / [How to get MySQLi error information in different environments](//stackoverflow.com/q/22662488) / [I need to debug PHP. What is my best choice?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4640421) / Right now this question is unanswerable (no concrete error or obvious defect in the shown excerpts).

Comment: @JohnConde Here is the actual error that i was getting in the first place:  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\MAMP\htdocs\process.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\process.php on line 43

Comment: That error means that the `prepare` failed. Are all your table and column names correct? What happens if you `echo $mysqli>error;`?

Comment: try to `var_dump($statement->error)` after the `prepare` the see error(s)

Comment: @Nick it actually apoints to the bind_param

Comment: @catcon "Notice: Trying to get property 'error' of non-object in C:\MAMP\htdocs\process.php on line 44
NULL", removeD the error property and it returned "bool(false)"

Comment: @AllanGodoy yes but the error on that line is because your call to `prepare` returned false, which indicates an error. You need to `echo $mysqli->error;` immediately after the `prepare`.

Comment: @catcon add this comment as the answear and i will mark it, it helped me to find the error, the problems was that one for one of my field names on my sql database was incorrect

Comment: @Nick Thank you for your help, this was the problem, i thought it would throw an exception, but it failed silently.

Comment: @AllanGodoy: glad that it helps, my comment only for clarifying, not actually an answer. If I post it in the answer section, it will attract downvote, lol